# Twitter typeahead autocomplete to dynamically added inputs

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using Twitter typeahead on my website and it works fine. But when I try to add new input dynamically it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Thank you for replies.

```
    var custom = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return d.tokens; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/invoice/loadItemOption?query=%QUERY'
    });

    custom.initialize();

    $('.typeahead_option_items').typeahead(null, {
          name: 'item_title[]',
          displayKey: 'invoice_item_option_title',
          source: custom.ttAdapter(),
          hint: (App.isRTL() ? false : true),
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, value) {
        console.log(value.invoice_item_option_title);
    });
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What I did was I wrapped this into a function

```
function typeahead_initialize() {
 var custom = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return d.tokens; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/invoice/loadItemOption?query=%QUERY'
    });

    custom.initialize();

    $('.typeahead_option_items').typeahead(null, {
          name: 'item_title[]',
          displayKey: 'invoice_item_option_title',
          source: custom.ttAdapter(),
          hint: (App.isRTL() ? false : true),
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, value) {
        console.log(value.invoice_item_option_title);
    });
}

typeahead_initialize();
```

and than before adding the dynamic input I run

```
$('.typeahead_option_items').typeahead('destroy');
```

and after the element is created

```
typeahead_initialize();
```

Works for me, hope this helps.

Comment: I receive TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function when I put $('.typeahead_option_items').typeahead('destroy'); in a function. But outside the function .typeahead is recognized and works. why ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple way to solve it, use the Function instead of Dynamic input.
I mean: 
typeahead="item in calculatedInput($viewValue)"

---

The root problem about using typeahead="item in $scope.dynamicArrayInput is:
When the model change -> ng-change and typeahead fire event **synchronize start**
So while calculatedInput() function doing something for get a dynamic input, the typeahead said model "jump in $scope.dynamicArrayInput then get something like $viewValue **RIGHT NOW**".
And then filter $viewValue in []. When calculatedInput() finish his work, typeahead already found nothing and do not fire event until u change model one more time.
So you always filter typeahead in (lastest - 1) dynamic array.