# Is it a good practice to reload script files?

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

I am using the `typeahead.js` plugin which can be used to add autocomplete features  to HTML input box.

So if you load the script and do

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" id="partNumberInput" aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Part Number">
```

The script will look for all the DOM elements with the class `typeahead` and add bunch of parent elements and does some other things which helps to give the autocomplete feature.

Now, I wanted to add input boxes dynamically using javascript append with the class of `typeahead`. Since the `typeahead` only runs once when the page loads at the beginning it does not get to do all the stuff I mentioned before.

Is this a scenario where I reload the script every time a user clicks a button to add another input box with `typeahead` class?

Comment: Check the documentation to see if there's a way to tell it to reinitialize itself.

Comment: Reloading the script is not necessary, you'd simply call `.typeahead()` on the new element. Which means this question is moot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321101/twitter-typeahead-autocomplete-to-dynamically-added-inputs

Comment: I don't see anything in the typeahead.js documentation about `class="typeahead"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first example in [the examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) shows how to call typeahead on any element in the page.

Rather than relying on putting a specific class on your elements so that typeahead detects them, you can call typeahead on your target element(s) using any class you want.

For example, if you have a brand new element that you dynamically placed into the DOM, and it has the class `whatever`, then you can load typeahead on that element by doing:

```js
$('.whatever').typeahead({
  // your options here
}, {
  // more options here, see examples
})
```

You would want to reload the script tag itself; that could have unintended (potentially detrimental) effects on your app.

In general, the form `$('.whatever').typeahead(...)` is how you generally call any jQuery plugin, in order to do operations with that plugin on the elements specified by the selector.